# Stirling Engine Cooled Engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, design, heat-transfer

Could a Stirling Engine replace the cooling system of an engine?

Instead of having a clutch and fan attached to the main drive shaft to cool an engine, could a Stirling Engine and clutch share that drive shaft to cool and add torque? What problems may arise?

Comment: Internal combustion engines use radiators to remove heat - how do you think a stirling engine will improve on that ? Weight, complexity etc

Comment: It think the Swedish Navy actually did this with some of their submarines. They ran off stirlings when running quiet, but also had diesels for surface running. I don't know the details of the plumbing, but it seems like a nobrainer for that application. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotland-class_submarine

Comment: I would also point out that the waste heat of conventional ICE's can be made arbitrarily small for a price that is probably less than the sterling. The coolant heat can be used to preheat both the charge air and fuel, and well as reheat exhaust prior to the final blowdown turbine stage. In ships, the waste heat is used to run low pressure evaporative desalinators, provide central heating, and for deicing in northern climates. Normally, we are more interested in power density than that last few percent of efficiency, but big ships are an exception.

Comment: Cost and size are issues, but the real killer is efficiency. The Carnot efficiency of a Stirling engine operating between Thot and Tcold is (Thot-Tcold)/Thot in absolute degress (either Kelvin or Rankine).  The Stirling STILL has to liberate heat energy from the cold side so you still need a radiator system. The actual efficicny for low delta T (as here) is usually under 50% of Carnot.
At 100 C = 373K and say 20C (293k) Out (hard) Zcarnot = (100-20)/373 = 21% or actual achievable under 10%. Even at Thot = 300C Zcarnot = (300-20)/*300+273) = ~ 48% and actual maybe 20%.

Comment: ... Recovered power is small compared to cost and size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Stirling engine is a way to remove heat from a heat source.  So  theoretically you could attach a Stirling engine to a radiator-like device and extract the heat using the engine.  We could then use the output of the engine to do work.  The most likely output would be an electric generator.

Trying to use the Stirling engine to add power directly to the crankshaft would likely be futile.  The power differentials would be large, and Stirling Engines don't have a good way to change speeds based on user (the driver) input.  The most likely result would be a gas engine spinning a Stirling engine and messing up the Stirling cycle completely.

While theoretically this could be done, the reality is that Stirling engines aren't very good at getting rid of heat, and are large clunky devices for what they do.  There is a reason they are not in widespread use.  If you had a lot of space and money to build Stirling engines around a stationary regular engine then your idea could work.  I fear, however, that this will never be a financially viable solution.

Comment: It's not just stirlings - *anything* that runs off low-quality heat is going to be big and clunky (low specific power and power density numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically yes. However the existing engine must run at a peak torque/rpm to run the engine to act as a heat pump.
Much like turbochargers, some companies are installing a small battery to run the turbos even when the engine is idle or off (start-stop systems), so when the engine reactivates its turbo lag is eliminated.

MSI developed a stirling cooling system for CPU gaming rigs [image]

But the thermal threshold and temperature is what makes and ideal engine run.

GM's Mild Hybrid system uses a oversized startup motor to run the engine when it's off or in low power mode, saving fuel to reduce winding startup. Stirling engine as a heat pump can be run on an additional battery[image]